# Results from sys_context('USERENV','HOST') differ using OCI/JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle-call-interface

We are using the `sys_context` function in oracle to identify the Hosts via sessions variables (we conntect some resources with the hosts). The results differ when we use `OCI` or `JDBC`:

```
using JDBC: select sys_context('USERENV','HOST') from dual;
Result: TEST267 (just the computername)

using OCI: select sys_context('USERENV','HOST') from dual;
Result: DOMANE\TEST267 (USERDOMAIN und COMPUTERNAME
```

Anyone knows how to get the same result (we need domain + computername) so that we can identify our hosts properly.

Comment: Hard to say. This information depends on information sent by a client to the server. There were times when JDBC drivers did not sent anything. Only Oracle can anwser this.

Comment: You could use `sys_context('USERENV','IP_ADDR')` to retrieve the IP address of the client (if hosts are using fixed IP addresses). However both methods cannot uniquely identify a specific host instance (IP addresses can change, Host names might have duplicates, at least over time).